# Couchbase filtering by field not in index

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I created this index :

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_orders` ON 
`order`(
distinct(
 ARRAY (s.dateTime) FOR s IN additionalStatus 
WHEN ((s.statusTypeCode = 'LOGISTICAL') AND (s.statusCode = 'CANCELLED' OR s.statusCode = 'TREATED')) END 
)
)
```

when i execute this query :

```
SELECT META(`order`).id FROM `order`
where ANY s in additionalStatus SATISFIES ( s.dateTime < 297798785) AND ((s.statusTypeCode = 'LOGISTICAL') AND (s.statusCode = 'CANCELLED' OR s.statusCode = 'TREATED'))  END
```

no index is hitted and i get this error :

> No index available on keyspace order that matches your query. Use
>   CREATE INDEX or CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create an index, or check that
>   your expected index is online

but when i add this where clause AND orderCategory != 'CA1' i get results

i think that some old version of my index (with same name) contain orderCategory field still exist and don't get removed even if i drop the index and recreate it.

Comment: ARRAY index WHEN clause has OR,IN,NOT clauses it is complex expression and may to pick index. Leave AND clauses only in WHEN clause of CREATE INDEX and others apply post scan filter.  CREATE INDEX `idx_orders` ON `order`( DISTINCT ARRAY s.dateTime FOR s IN additionalStatus 
WHEN s.statusTypeCode = 'LOGISTICAL' END )